# org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to find class with given class loader for unmarshalling

Tags: ignite

Using Ignite 2.1, I start first node in default server mode with peer class loading enabled from command line. I see the following line in the logs:

When I start the second node (using IgniteSpringBean on a tomcat server, in client mode) I am getting the following error, even though peer class loading is enabled:

```
org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to find class with given class loader for unmarshalling (make sure same versions of all classes are available on all nodes or enable peer-class-loading) [clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2,...
```

Visor tells me that both the server and the client node are in the topology and both have peer class loading enabled...

Server logs:

```
     [vagrant@tw apache-ignite-fabric-2.1.0-bin]$ ./bin/ignite.sh ./config/example-default.xml -v
    Ignite Command Line Startup, ver. 2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a
    2017 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation

    [13:41:51,967][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] 

    >>>    __________  ________________  
    >>>   /  _/ ___/ |/ /  _/_  __/ __/  
    >>>  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / _/    
    >>> /___/\___/_/|_/___/ /_/ /___/   
    >>> 
    >>> ver. 2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a
    >>> 2017 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
    >>> 
    >>> Ignite documentation: http://ignite.apache.org

    [13:41:51,967][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Config URL: file:/home/vagrant/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-2.1.0-bin/./config/example-default.xml
    [13:41:51,968][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Daemon mode: off
    [13:41:51,968][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] OS: Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 amd64
    [13:41:51,968][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] OS user: vagrant
    [13:41:51,968][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] PID: 8122
    [13:41:51,968][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Language runtime: Java Platform API Specification ver. 1.8
    [13:41:51,968][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] VM information: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_60-b27 Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.60-b23
    [13:41:51,970][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] VM total memory: 0.97GB
    [13:41:51,970][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Remote Management [restart: on, REST: on, JMX (remote: on, port: 49122, auth: off, ssl: off)]
    [13:41:51,970][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] IGNITE_HOME=/home/vagrant/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-2.1.0-bin
    [13:41:51,971][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] VM arguments: [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+AggressiveOpts, -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m, -DIGNITE_QUIET=false, -DIGNITE_SUCCESS_FILE=/home/vagrant/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-2.1.0-bin/work/ignite_success_96df797d-5531-4b3e-b396-5f44cdc1470e, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=49122, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false, -DIGNITE_HOME=/home/vagrant/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-2.1.0-bin, -DIGNITE_PROG_NAME=./bin/ignite.sh]
    [13:41:51,973][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] System cache's MemoryPolicy size is configured to 40 MB. Use MemoryConfiguration.systemCacheMemorySize property to change the setting.
    [13:41:51,980][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Configured caches [in 'sysMemPlc' memoryPolicy: ['ignite-sys-cache']]
    [13:41:51,980][WARNING][main][IgniteKernal] Peer class loading is enabled (disable it in production for performance and deployment consistency reasons)
    [13:41:52,002][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] 3-rd party licenses can be found at: /home/vagrant/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-2.1.0-bin/libs/licenses
    [13:41:52,077][INFO][main][IgnitePluginProcessor] Configured plugins:
    [13:41:52,078][INFO][main][IgnitePluginProcessor]   ^-- None
    [13:41:52,078][INFO][main][IgnitePluginProcessor] 
    [13:41:52,138][INFO][main][TcpCommunicationSpi] Successfully bound communication NIO server to TCP port [port=47100, locHost=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, selectorsCnt=4, selectorSpins=0, pairedConn=false]
    [13:41:52,150][WARNING][main][TcpCommunicationSpi] Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
    [13:41:52,169][WARNING][main][NoopCheckpointSpi] Checkpoints are disabled (to enable configure any GridCheckpointSpi implementation)
    [13:41:52,196][WARNING][main][GridCollisionManager] Collision resolution is disabled (all jobs will be activated upon arrival).
    [13:41:52,197][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
    [13:41:52,516][INFO][main][SqlListenerProcessor] SQL connector processor has started on TCP port 10800
    [13:41:52,550][INFO][main][GridTcpRestProtocol] Command protocol successfully started [name=TCP binary, host=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, port=11211]
    [13:41:52,593][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Non-loopback local IPs: 10.0.10.103, 10.0.2.15, fe80:0:0:0:a00:27ff:fe51:d0d8%eth0, fe80:0:0:0:a00:27ff:fee7:1d4f%eth1
    [13:41:52,593][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Enabled local MACs: 08002751D0D8, 080027E71D4F
    [13:41:52,637][INFO][main][TcpDiscoverySpi] Successfully bound to TCP port [port=47500, localHost=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, locNodeId=2a929c01-f8a6-4b14-9857-88eaa2b58a87]
    [13:41:54,030][INFO][exchange-worker-#28%null%][time] Started exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=12, minorTopVer=0], crd=true, evt=10, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=2a929c01-f8a6-4b14-9857-88eaa2b58a87, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.0.10.103, 10.0.2.15, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/10.0.10.103:47500, /10.0.2.15:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=12, intOrder=7, lastExchangeTime=1505328114016, loc=true, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a, isClient=false], evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=2a929c01-f8a6-4b14-9857-88eaa2b58a87, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.0.10.103, 10.0.2.15, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/10.0.10.103:47500, /10.0.2.15:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=12, intOrder=7, lastExchangeTime=1505328114016, loc=true, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a, isClient=false], customEvt=null]
    [13:41:54,042][WARNING][exchange-worker-#28%null%][IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager] No user-defined default MemoryPolicy found; system default of 1GB size will be used.
    [13:41:54,299][INFO][exchange-worker-#28%null%][GridCacheProcessor] Started cache [name=ignite-sys-cache, memoryPolicyName=sysMemPlc, mode=REPLICATED, atomicity=TRANSACTIONAL]
    [13:41:54,302][INFO][exchange-worker-#28%null%][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Finished waiting for partition release future [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=12, minorTopVer=0], waitTime=0ms]
    [13:41:54,333][INFO][exchange-worker-#28%null%][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Snapshot initialization completed [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=12, minorTopVer=0], time=0ms]
    [13:41:54,347][INFO][exchange-worker-#28%null%][time] Finished exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=12, minorTopVer=0], crd=true]
    [13:41:54,350][INFO][exchange-worker-#28%null%][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] Skipping rebalancing (nothing scheduled) [top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=12, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_JOINED, node=2a929c01-f8a6-4b14-9857-88eaa2b58a87]
    [13:41:54,450][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Performance suggestions for grid  (fix if possible)
    [13:41:54,451][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] To disable, set -DIGNITE_PERFORMANCE_SUGGESTIONS_DISABLED=true
    [13:41:54,451][INFO][main][IgniteKernal]   ^-- Disable grid events (remove 'includeEventTypes' from configuration)
    [13:41:54,451][INFO][main][IgniteKernal]   ^-- Enable G1 Garbage Collector (add '-XX:+UseG1GC' to JVM options)
    [13:41:54,451][INFO][main][IgniteKernal]   ^-- Set max direct memory size if getting 'OOME: Direct buffer memory' (add '-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]' to JVM options)
    [13:41:54,451][INFO][main][IgniteKernal]   ^-- Disable processing of calls to System.gc() (add '-XX:+DisableExplicitGC' to JVM options)
    [13:41:54,451][INFO][main][IgniteKernal]   ^-- Speed up flushing of dirty pages by OS (alter vm.dirty_expire_centisecs parameter by setting to 500)
    [13:41:54,451][INFO][main][IgniteKernal]   ^-- Reduce pages swapping ratio (set vm.swappiness=10)
    [13:41:54,451][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Refer to this page for more performance suggestions: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jvm-and-system-tuning
    [13:41:54,451][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] 
    [13:41:54,451][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] To start Console Management & Monitoring run ignitevisorcmd.{sh|bat}
    [13:41:54,451][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] 
    [13:41:54,459][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] 

    >>> +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
    >>> Ignite ver. 2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a97e9a4c9d73d40ce76d1504c14ba1940
    >>> +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
    >>> OS name: Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 amd64
    >>> CPU(s): 1
    >>> Heap: 1.0GB
    >>> VM name: 8122@tw.dna.com
    >>> Local node [ID=2A929C01-F8A6-4B14-9857-88EAA2B58A87, order=12, clientMode=false]
    >>> Local node addresses: [10.0.10.103/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.0.2.15/10.0.10.103, /10.0.2.15, /127.0.0.1]
    >>> Local ports: TCP:10800 TCP:11211 TCP:47100 UDP:47400 TCP:47500 

    [13:41:54,462][INFO][main][GridDiscoveryManager] Topology snapshot [ver=12, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=1, heap=1.0GB]
    [13:42:54,444][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#15%null%][IgniteKernal] 
    Metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
        ^-- Node [id=2a929c01, name=null, uptime=00:01:00:007]
        ^-- H/N/C [hosts=1, nodes=1, CPUs=1]
        ^-- CPU [cur=2.33%, avg=1.57%, GC=0%]
        ^-- PageMemory [pages=200]
        ^-- Heap [used=107MB, free=89.12%, comm=989MB]
        ^-- Non heap [used=36MB, free=97.59%, comm=37MB]
        ^-- Public thread pool [active=0, idle=0, qSize=0]
        ^-- System thread pool [active=0, idle=6, qSize=0]
        ^-- Outbound messages queue [size=0]
    [13:43:46,444][INFO][disco-event-worker-#27%null%][GridDiscoveryManager] Added new node to topology: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=c8c42745-f838-48ea-9145-5783a6f77681, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.0.10.101, 10.0.2.15, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /10.0.10.101:0, /10.0.2.15:0], discPort=0, order=13, intOrder=8, lastExchangeTime=1505328226398, loc=false, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a, isClient=true]
    [13:43:46,446][INFO][disco-event-worker-#27%null%][GridDiscoveryManager] Topology snapshot [ver=13, servers=1, clients=1, CPUs=2, heap=3.0GB]
    [13:43:46,448][INFO][exchange-worker-#28%null%][time] Started exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=13, minorTopVer=0], crd=true, evt=10, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=2a929c01-f8a6-4b14-9857-88eaa2b58a87, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.0.10.103, 10.0.2.15, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/10.0.10.103:47500, /10.0.2.15:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=12, intOrder=7, lastExchangeTime=1505328226435, loc=true, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a, isClient=false], evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=2a929c01-f8a6-4b14-9857-88eaa2b58a87, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.0.10.103, 10.0.2.15, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/10.0.10.103:47500, /10.0.2.15:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=12, intOrder=7, lastExchangeTime=1505328226435, loc=true, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a, isClient=false], customEvt=null]
    [13:43:46,448][INFO][exchange-worker-#28%null%][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Snapshot initialization completed [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=13, minorTopVer=0], time=0ms]
    [13:43:46,449][INFO][exchange-worker-#28%null%][time] Finished exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=13, minorTopVer=0], crd=true]
    [13:43:46,449][INFO][exchange-worker-#28%null%][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] Skipping rebalancing (nothing scheduled) [top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=13, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_JOINED, node=c8c42745-f838-48ea-9145-5783a6f77681]
    [13:43:47,121][INFO][grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-0-#17%null%][TcpCommunicationSpi] Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/10.0.10.103:47100, rmtAddr=/10.0.10.101:54857]
    [13:43:47,357][INFO][exchange-worker-#28%null%][time] Started exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=13, minorTopVer=1], crd=true, evt=18, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=2a929c01-f8a6-4b14-9857-88eaa2b58a87, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.0.10.103, 10.0.2.15, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/10.0.10.103:47500, /10.0.2.15:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=12, intOrder=7, lastExchangeTime=1505328227343, loc=true, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a, isClient=false], evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=2a929c01-f8a6-4b14-9857-88eaa2b58a87, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.0.10.103, 10.0.2.15, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/10.0.10.103:47500, /10.0.2.15:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=12, intOrder=7, lastExchangeTime=1505328227343, loc=true, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a, isClient=false], customEvt=DynamicCacheChangeBatch [id=dcedd8c7e51-9d6cee64-90a5-4c0b-a1ed-b4c7a1697bfb, reqs=[DynamicCacheChangeRequest [cacheName=ignite-sys-atomic-cache@dna-EVENT_DELIVERY_SET, hasCfg=true, nodeId=c8c42745-f838-48ea-9145-5783a6f77681, clientStartOnly=false, stop=false, destroy=false]], exchangeActions=ExchangeActions [startCaches=[ignite-sys-atomic-cache@dna-EVENT_DELIVERY_SET], stopCaches=null, startGrps=[dna-EVENT_DELIVERY_SET], stopGrps=[], resetParts=null, stateChangeRequest=null], startCaches=false]]
    [13:43:47,378][INFO][exchange-worker-#28%null%][GridCacheProcessor] Started cache [name=ignite-sys-atomic-cache@dna-EVENT_DELIVERY_SET, group=dna-EVENT_DELIVERY_SET, memoryPolicyName=default, mode=PARTITIONED, atomicity=TRANSACTIONAL]
    [13:43:47,379][INFO][exchange-worker-#28%null%][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Finished waiting for partition release future [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=13, minorTopVer=1], waitTime=0ms]
    [13:43:47,496][INFO][exchange-worker-#28%null%][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Snapshot initialization completed [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=13, minorTopVer=1], time=0ms]
    [13:43:47,512][INFO][exchange-worker-#28%null%][time] Finished exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=13, minorTopVer=1], crd=true]
    [13:43:47,515][INFO][exchange-worker-#28%null%][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] Skipping rebalancing (nothing scheduled) [top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=13, minorTopVer=1], evt=DISCOVERY_CUSTOM_EVT, node=c8c42745-f838-48ea-9145-5783a6f77681]
    [13:43:47,558][INFO][exchange-worker-#28%null%][time] Started exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=13, minorTopVer=2], crd=true, evt=18, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=2a929c01-f8a6-4b14-9857-88eaa2b58a87, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.0.10.103, 10.0.2.15, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/10.0.10.103:47500, /10.0.2.15:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=12, intOrder=7, lastExchangeTime=1505328227557, loc=true, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a, isClient=false], evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=2a929c01-f8a6-4b14-9857-88eaa2b58a87, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.0.10.103, 10.0.2.15, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/10.0.10.103:47500, /10.0.2.15:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=12, intOrder=7, lastExchangeTime=1505328227557, loc=true, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a, isClient=false], customEvt=DynamicCacheChangeBatch [id=3dedd8c7e51-9d6cee64-90a5-4c0b-a1ed-b4c7a1697bfb, reqs=[DynamicCacheChangeRequest [cacheName=datastructures_ATOMIC_PARTITIONED_0@dna-EVENT_DELIVERY_SET, hasCfg=true, nodeId=c8c42745-f838-48ea-9145-5783a6f77681, clientStartOnly=false, stop=false, destroy=false]], exchangeActions=ExchangeActions [startCaches=[datastructures_ATOMIC_PARTITIONED_0@dna-EVENT_DELIVERY_SET], stopCaches=null, startGrps=[], stopGrps=[], resetParts=null, stateChangeRequest=null], startCaches=false]]
    [13:43:47,597][INFO][exchange-worker-#28%null%][GridCacheProcessor] Started cache [name=datastructures_ATOMIC_PARTITIONED_0@dna-EVENT_DELIVERY_SET, group=dna-EVENT_DELIVERY_SET, memoryPolicyName=default, mode=PARTITIONED, atomicity=ATOMIC]
    [13:43:47,597][INFO][exchange-worker-#28%null%][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Finished waiting for partition release future [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=13, minorTopVer=2], waitTime=0ms]
    [13:43:47,623][INFO][exchange-worker-#28%null%][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Snapshot initialization completed [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=13, minorTopVer=2], time=0ms]
    [13:43:47,625][INFO][exchange-worker-#28%null%][time] Finished exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=13, minorTopVer=2], crd=true]
    [13:43:47,626][INFO][exchange-worker-#28%null%][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] Skipping rebalancing (nothing scheduled) [top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=13, minorTopVer=2], evt=DISCOVERY_CUSTOM_EVT, node=c8c42745-f838-48ea-9145-5783a6f77681]
    [13:43:47,915][SEVERE][tcp-disco-msg-worker-#2%null%][TcpDiscoverySpi] Failed to unmarshal discovery custom message.
    class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to find class with given class loader for unmarshalling (make sure same versions of all classes are available on all nodes or enable peer-class-loading) [clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2, cls=scan.fragment.node.ignite.VersionedInterceptor]
        at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:124)
        at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:94)
        at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:143)
        at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:82)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshal(IgniteUtils.java:9733)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.messages.TcpDiscoveryCustomEventMessage.message(TcpDiscoveryCustomEventMessage.java:81)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.notifyDiscoveryListener(ServerImpl.java:5436)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processCustomMessage(ServerImpl.java:5321)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processMessage(ServerImpl.java:2629)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processMessage(ServerImpl.java:2420)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$MessageWorkerAdapter.body(ServerImpl.java:6576)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.body(ServerImpl.java:2506)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scan.fragment.node.ignite.VersionedInterceptor
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.forName(IgniteUtils.java:8465)
        at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshallerObjectInputStream.resolveClass(JdkMarshallerObjectInputStream.java:54)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
        at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1900)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
        at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:121)
        ... 12 more
```

Comment: Adding the necessary /jar files to Ignite/libs results in everything working, but this should not be required with peer class loading enabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Peer class loading is working with Compute Grid [1] only. It looks like your `VersionedInterceptor` is part of cache configuration (implementation of `CacheInterceptor`?), such classes have to be explicitly deployed on all nodes prior to cluster start.

Comment: You're right - I added the VersionedInterceptor class (and some other that were used to to create caches..for example IgniteCache<Long, Customer>) to the Ignite libs folder and my client connected...However when I execute a IgniteCallable from a class called IgniteGridManager: `..ignite.compute().call(callable);` I get another ClassNotFoundException: IgniteGridManager, even though that class is not referenced in the callable at all. Adding additional jars to libs clears things up, as does enabling peer class loading. I do not expect the invoking IgniteGridManager class to be needed however..?

Comment: If you have this exception, then `IgniteGridManager` was serialized. In case you use anonymous classes, try to convert them to static inner classes

Comment: The jobs in IgniteGridManager were indeed anonymous. I created implementations and moved them into one of the JARs in the libs folder and everything worked. Thanks for your help.